# Match timestamps in WebVTT files with sed

Tags: regex, text, sed, subtitle, webvtt

I have the following PCRE2 regex that works to match and remove timestamp lines in a .webVTT subtitle file (the default for YouTube):

```
^[0-9].:[0-9].:[0-9].+$
```

This changes this:

```
00:00:00.126 --> 00:00:10.058
How are you today?

00:00:10.309 --> 00:00:19.272
Not bad, you?

00:00:19.559 --> 00:00:29.365
Been better.
```

To this:

```
How are you today?

Not bad, you?

Been better.
```

How would I convert this PCRE2 regex to an idiomatic (read: sane-looking) equivalent for `sed`'s flavour of regex?

Comment: I suggest to replace `+` with `\+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your regex with `sed`

```
$ sed -En '/^[0-9].:[0-9].:[0-9].+$/!p' file
How are you today?

Not bad, you?

Been better.
```

Or, do not match lines that end with an integer

```
$ sed  -n '/[0-9]$/!p' file
How are you today?

Not bad, you?

Been better.
```

Comment: The first one gives me a "no such file or directory" error when I try and use it in the following command: `sed -e '1,4d' -En '/^[0-9].:[0-9].:[0-9].+$/!p' "input file.vtt" > test.txt`.

Comment: I replaced it to make the command clearer - using tab completion for the file on my shell still results in the error.

Comment: Could it be something to do with trying to combine `-e` and `-E`? I was previously using two invocations of `-e` in the same `sed` command but maybe `-E` is not a drop-in replacement?

Comment: This is the full command that gives me the "no such file or directory" error: `sed -e '1,4d' -En '/^[0-9].:[0-9].:[0-9].+$/!p' "my file.vtt" > test.txt`.

Comment: @HashimAziz Does this work `sed -En '1,4d;/^[0-9].:[0-9].:[0-9].+$/!p' "my file.vtt" > test.txt`

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly, as does adding the spaces back between `/ ! p`, so I suppose I was right in my hunch that -e and -E can't be combined, which you solved by integrating the first command into the -E.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is not a specific PCRE2 pattern, only using sed you have to escape the `\+` to make it a quantifier for 1 or more times.

At the positions that you use a dot to match any character (and looking at the example data) there is a digit as well.

You could make the pattern a bit more specific, and omit the quantifier at all. Just prevent the line from printing if the pattern matches.

```
sed -n '/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9]/!p' file
```

- `-n` prevents the default printing in sed
- `!p` prints the line if the pattern does not match

Output

```
How are you today?

Not bad, you?

Been better.
```